# "sudo conjure-up --bootstrap-to juju" command is not working

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

This is my first time, i am trying to install openstack on ubuntu, using vms. I have a private network for PXE boot only managed by `maas` vm and have other vms as nodes. One vm which i want to setup landscape, i named it `juju` in MAAS's nodes list. So its name is `juju.maas` or `juju`. But whenever i execute `sudo conjure-up --bootstrap-to juju` or `sudo conjure-up --bootstrap-to juju.maas`, i get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/471/bin/conjure-up", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('conjure-up==2.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'conjure-up')()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/471/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/app.py", line 204, in main
utils.info("")
  File "/snap/conjure-up/471/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/utils.py", line 244, in info
send_msg(msg, 'info', 'green')
  File "/snap/conjure-up/471/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/utils.py", line 232, in send_msg
    if app.argv.debug:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
```

Any help ??

Comment: To start, you shouldn't need to use `sudo`. I'll make sure the maintainers see this, but you may want to just add `--debug` to see if it progresses.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Few minutes ago i tried with both sudo and non sudo, nothing was working. I removed conjure-up. Recommisioned the machine. Now atleast installer is showing up, but it is saying something wrong with my installation at last step.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Increasing RAM to 5 GB for juju. And i purged maas installation and after clean installation setting api location worked for me.

Comment: Also the bug you are seeing has been fixed in https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/969